# Trying to figure out SSRS report delay

Tags: ssrs-2012

I'm writing a report in SSRS that is taking a long time to run. Here's what's happening:  I press the view report button at 9:46AM and at 9:56AM, I finally see the Loading pop up.  The report then comes up a minute later.  I stuck some debugging displays in there that says the following:

```
 Start: 3/30/2016 9:56:16 AM
 End: 3/30/2016 9:56:18 AM
 Elapsed: 0:01
```

So for some odd reason, SSRS is waiting ten minutes before running the report.  This is a problem because the deployed report is timing out.  How can I determine what is going on between the time I press the button to the time the report actually starts to get processed?

Additional: The logs don't show anything that leaps out as a problem.
SQL:

Term:

```
Select Term_Code, Term_Seq_Id, Start_Date, Long_Desc
From TERM
Where (End_Date Between '2004-05-07' AND GetDate())
Order By Term_Seq_Id Desc
```

RestrictionCount:

```
Select Count(*) as RestrictionCount from ReportUser Where LoginID = @User
```

Sections:

```
Select distinct Sctn_id_code, subj_code, crse_code, sctn_code, sctn_term_code
from siscrsi
where sctn_term_code = @Term and subj_code in (@Subject) and crse_code in (@Courses) and (Pid = @Instructors or @Instructors = '<ALL>')
order by sctn_term_code, subj_code, crse_code, sctn_code
```

Colleges:

```
If @RestrictionCount = 0
   Select Coll_Code, Full_Name
   From College
   Order by Coll_Code
Else
   Select Distinct c.Coll_Code, c.Full_Name
   From College as c
   Inner Join sirssoctonlineforms.dbo.ReportUser as ru on ru.Coll_Code = c.Coll_Code
   Where ru.LoginID = @User
   Order by Coll_Code
```

Subjects:

```
Select distinct subj_code
From section_info
Where sctn_term_code = @Term and coll_code = @College and dept_code in (@Department)
order by subj_code
```

CoursesList:

```
Select Distinct Crse_Code, Subj_Code
From SISCRSI
Where Sctn_Term_Code = @Term
  and Subj_Code = @Subject 
  and ((pid = @Instructors) or (@Instructors = '<ALL>'))
Order by Crse_Code
```

Instructors:

```
Select 'blank' as sctn_term_code, '<ALL>' as pid, '<ALL>' as name
union all
Select distinct sctn_term_code, pid, name 
From sisinfo.dbo.SISCRSI instructor
where sctn_term_code = @Term 
  and subj_code = @Subject 
order by name
```

Departments:

```
If @RestrictionCount = 0
   Select Dept_Code, Full_Name
   From Dept
   Where coll_code in (@College)
   order by Dept_Code
Else
   Select Distinct d.Dept_Code, Full_Name
   From Dept d
   Inner Join sirssoctonlineforms.dbo.ReportUser as ru on ru.Dept_code =  d.Dept_Code
   Where ru.LoginID = @User and d.Coll_Code in (@College)
   Order by Dept_Code
```

Questions:

```
Select count(*) as questionCount
From Questions q
Inner Join Form_Question fq on fq.Question_Id = q.Question_Id and     q.Question_Format_Group <> 'Text'
Inner Join Response_Sets rs on rs.Form_Id = fq.Form_Id
Where rs.Sctn_Id_Code in (@SectionCodes)
```

NumberQuestions:

```
Select Top 1 dView.[Section Code], rSets.Form_ID, max(fq.Question_Order) as LastQuestion
From Denormalized_V as dView
Inner Join Response_sets as rSets on rSets.Sctn_ID_Code = dView.[Section Code]
Inner Join Form_Question as fq on fq.Form_ID = rSets.Form_ID
Where dView.[Section Code] in (@SectionCodes)
Group by [Section Code], rSets.Form_ID
Order by LastQuestion desc
```

InstructorPID:

```
If @Instructors = '<ALL>'
   Select 'NoName' as Name, 'Z000000000' as pid
Else Begin
   Select top 1 Name, pid
   From SISCRSI
   Where name = @Instructors
End
```

OptOutCount:

```
Select SectionInfo.Sctn_Id_Code as [Course Section ID], SectionInfo.Student_Cnt as [Total Students], Declined.Declined as [Total Declined]
From SECTION_INFO SectionInfo
Inner Join (
   select Sctn_Id_Code, count(Sctn_Id_Code) as [Declined]
   From declined
   Where Form_Id > 1 
     and Sctn_ID_Code in (@SectionCodes)
   Group By Sctn_Id_Code
) as Declined on SectionInfo.Sctn_Id_Code = Declined.Sctn_Id_Code
```

The main report query (that takes less than three seconds to run):

```
If @nonTextQuestionCount > 0
   Select *
   From (
      Select si.Sctn_Id_Code as [Section Code],  
             si.Subj_Code as [Subject], 
             si.Crse_Code as [Course], si.Sctn_Code as [Course Section], 
             fq.Question_Order as [Question Number], 
             Case r.Instructor_PID 
                When 'ALL' Then 
                   @InstructorName 
                Else 
                   CRSI.Name 
             End as [Instructor Name], 
             rs.Set_Id as [Respondent Code], 
             Case rp.reply_ID 
                When 1 Then 
                   r.response 
                Else rp.Reply_Text 
             End as [Reply Text]
      From SECTION_INFO si 
      Inner Join Response_Sets rs on si.sctn_id_code = rs.Sctn_Id_Code 
      Inner Join Responses r on r.Set_Id = rs.Set_Id 
      Inner Join Questions q on q.Question_Id = r.Question_Id 
      Inner Join Form_Question fq on fq.Question_Id = q.Question_Id and fq.Form_Id = rs.Form_Id 
      Inner Join Forms f on f.Form_Id = fq.Form_Id 
      Inner Join Replies rp on rp.Reply_Id = r.Reply_Id 
      Left Outer Join SISINFO..SISCRSI CRSI on CRSI.PID = r.Instructor_PID 
                      and si.Sctn_Id_Code = CRSI.sctn_id_code
      Where si.Sctn_Term_Code = @Term 
        and si.Subj_Code = @Subject and si.Crse_Code in (@Courses) 
        and ((@Instructors = '<ALL>') or (r.Instructor_PID = @Instructors or r.Instructor_PID = 'ALL')) 
        and si.Sctn_Code in (@Sections) 
        and fq.Form_Id <> 1                     
   ) as q1 
   Pivot (Max([Reply Text]) For [Question Number] in 
   ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], 
    [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31], [32], [33], [34], [35], 
    [36], [37], [38], [39], [40], [41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49], [50], [51], [52], 
    [53], [54], [55], [56], [57], [58], [59], [60], [61], [62], [63], [64])) 
   as p
   group by subject, course, [subject], [course section], [Section Code], [Instructor_Pid], 
   [respondent code],[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], 
   [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31], 
   [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40], [41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], 
   [48], [49], [50], [51], [52], [53], [54], [55], [56], [57], [58], [59], [60], [61], [62], [63], [64]
   order by [subject], [course], [course section]
Else
   Select * From
   (
   Select rSets.set_id, dView.[Course section], dView.[Subject], dView.Course, dView.[Instructor pid],
          answers.response, formQuestion.Question_Order, dView.[Section Code]
   From Denormalized_V as dView
   Inner Join response_sets as rSets on rSets.sctn_id_code = dView.[section code]
   Inner Join responses as answers on answers.set_id = rSets.set_id
   Inner Join questions as questions on questions.question_id = answers.question_id
   Inner Join form_question as formQuestion on formQuestion.question_id = questions.question_id
   where Term = @Term and 
         [Subject] = @Subject and 
         Course in (@Courses) and
         ((@Instructors = '<ALL>') or (dView.[Instructor Pid] = @Instructors or dView.[Instructor Pid] = 'ALL')) and  
         dView.[Course Section] in (@Sections) and dView.[Survey Type] <> 'SOCT'
) t
Pivot (max(response) for question_order in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])) as pvt
```

Comment: why don't you post the query for each data-set, so we can see what is slowing down your report.

Comment: I added the 14 queries as requested.

Comment: Where did you get the log? Is it possible you can access ReportServerService log file in your SSRS folder and then verify when the session was rendered?

Comment: In my hopinion, the problem isn't in the queries, which should run when there's the Loading screen on. I'm not quite sure, but I guess that the interval before the Loading message is for connecting to the database server. While it may be useless, it could be worth considering the case.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a better result if you deploy on the report server and run the  report from there. 
Anyway i believe that the reason of the delay is caused by the order of the data-sets.
I mean the order on the data-set list some how seems to indicate the order of execution. When you link the data-sets of the parameters, the last on the list is the last to be executed.This may be the reason of your delay.
You probably have to put the data-sets of the parameters on top of the list. Doing this you ensure that they are executed first, and don't wait for the other data-sets to be generated.

Comment: When it's deployed, it times out.  We're going to talk to Microsoft to see what they say.